# How to set correct indentation with cinoptons and cinkeys in switch statement?

Tags: vim

I'm using indentation style of C++ like LLVM, and clang-format. I need options to be like that:

```
set cinoptions=:0,g0,(0,Ws,l
set autoindent
set smartindent
set cinkeys=0{,0},0),:,0#,!^F,o,O,e
set cinwords=if,else,while,do,for
```

Problem with that, that whenever i refer to namespace  and press **namespace:** - it triggers :0 option. When pressed second : - it triggers back. Yes, all is correct. But triggering always for : - very bad for my brain. I wanna static behavior. Not whenever i'm trying to use some namespace and press double :. I need triggering :0 only for the **case** in **switch** statement. I hope you can understand what i'm talking about. Please help.

```
switch(number) {
case 4: // i wanna triggering of:0 only for this line of code.
  cout << "Good indentation";
  break;
}
if (true) {
namespace: // NOT FOR THAT!
  namespace:: // triggers back - all is correct. First triggering is very bad!
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `L0`; see `:h cino-L`. It's -1 by default, which means jumping to col 1. It's worth noting the wording in the documentation as well: "If N is non-negative, the indent of the label will be the prevailing indent minus N." -- that's why `N = 0` works. It preserves the current indentation level by not subtracting anything from it, and through that, avoiding the jumping.

It only affects [labels](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements#Labels) and not the switch statements' `case x:`. Note that this means if you want labels to be indented differently, but don't want jumping for the `::` operator, you'll probably need to find an LSP with that type of indent support, because cino doesn't support that. You'll either have to live with it jumping on the first `:` and back on `::`, or not having label indentation automatically differ from your normal source code indentation, and having `=` reset any manual changes you do to label indentation.

Anyway, it also means `:0` was never actually triggered. `cino`'s default options meant `L-1` was triggered on `namespace:` - switch case labels aren't the same as normal labels, which meant another option was to blame.

And finally, for the sake of completeness:

```
set cinoptions=:0,g0,(0,Ws,l,L0
```